# Como saber si una cadena comienza con ciertos caracteres

Tags: c#

sabe alguien como puedo saber si una cadena comienza con: por ejemplo ca si existe alguna funcion para esto.

Ejemplo:

```
string cadena = "test";
string comienza = "te";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Utiliza  la función StartsWith de la clase string

```
string cadena = "test";
string comienza = "te";

if (cadena.StartsWith(comienza))
{
    //la cadena si comienza 
}
```

Comment: Gracias user943500 por su pronta respuesta, me funciono perfecto